# Command Line Arguments Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an executable file `a.out` in my workspace that I am trying to call with the argument `hello.txt`.

When I run `./a.out hello.txt` in the terminal, it works. However, when try to do this with VSC, `hello.txt` is not getting passed to the executable.

I've verified my json files extensively, but I cannot figure out where the issue is coming from. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My `tasks.json` and `launch.json` are below:

**tasks.json:**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc-9",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/a.out"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**launch.json:**

```
{
    "name": "C Launch",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
    "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/hello.txt"],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```